# wpf Disable Tabstop globally

Tags: c#, wpf

I can not find a way to globally disable tabstop for every element that is created or will be created inside a window... So that tab navigation would only work for those elements where I write in KeyboardNavigation.TabStop="true".
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can put this in your application's `Startup` event:

```
Control.IsTabStopProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(Control),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
```

It changes the default value of the `IsTabStop` property to false.

Comment: Perfect. This lets me manually specify which controls I should be able to tab to, which is a whole lot easier than trying to figure out which control is a tab stop that shouldn't be.